# How do I get my nav bar to stick to the top of the screen when you scroll?

Tags: html, css, position, nav, sticky

I am trying to use overflow: sticky; to get my nav bar to stop at the top of the screen when scrolling but its changing nothing, I've seen people say to set margin and padding on ul to 0 which I've done but had no change, I've also tried getting rid of overflow: hidden but that gets rid of the background color of the bar. HTML and CSS below.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Assets/css/site.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src = "Assets/images/Header1.jpg" id = "headImage">

        <nav id = "navBar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href = "index.html" class = "active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href = "weapons.html">Weapons</a></li>
                <li><a hred = "maps.html">Maps</a></li>
                <li><a href = "modes.html">Modes</a></li>
                <li><a href = "contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
    </header>


    
    <footer>

    </footer>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background-color: rgb(43, 23, 23);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 1000px;
}

.active{
    background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
}

#headImage{
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 50%;
}

#navBar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
}

#navBar li{
    float: left;
}

#navBar a{
    display:block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navBar a:hover{
    background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
}
```

Comment: you dont need to use `webkit` for `sticky`.`Sticky` is supported by default by every browser with exeption of IE. Dont use `float` for styling purpose. Its hsould only be used for floating images within a pargraph. you can either use `flexboxes` or simply declare a list element to be `inline` and align it with `text-align`. Use the `position: sticky;` on the nabar itsel not on the `ul`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of things to fix your code that not necessarily has something to do with your code.

Mandatory:

1. remove `-webkit-sticky;` as it is useless. Firefox supports `sticky` be default as every other browser with exeption of IE. The use of -webkit- is outdated since many years.
2. they `sticky` should be applied to the `navbar` itself not just the list.
3. The Navbar needs to be excldued from the header. If it is a child of the `header`, it will be forced to stay within the child and therefor pulled out of the screen.

Optional:

using `float` for styling purpose is not only outdated but never was a thing. It was mis-used by many out of its actual purpose. It should only be used for floating images within a paragraph. For that use, delcare the list simply as `inline-block`. Then it can be aligned with `text-align`.

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(43, 23, 23);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 1000px;
}

.active {
  background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
}

#headImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
}

#navBar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#navBar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#navBar li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#navBar a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#navBar a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="Assets/images/Header1.jpg" id="headImage">
</header>
<nav id="navBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="weapons.html">Weapons</a></li>
    <li><a hred="maps.html">Maps</a></li>
    <li><a href="modes.html">Modes</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>



<footer>
</footer>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks very much I didn't know you could do that text-align thing. The float was melting my brain lol.

Also, just now discovered the header problem, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: is there any way we can detect the device's status bar's (e.g. Android's status bar for Chrome) height so that we are able to know what value to use for top? i've been struggling with the status bar being in the way. using `angular`. tried using `css` in the `js` code but to no avail.

Comment: @domster that is a completely different question. Besides that, the status bar is an OS thing and not part of the browser. As such it is not part of the viewport (as it lies outside of the browser). There is no way to detect its height, change it or obscure it. As said, it is not part of the browser but an OS feature. In no case, you could ever overwrite it.

Comment: @tacoshy thank you for your reply! yes you're right on that. it's odd how most websites manage to have the navbar nicely stick below the status bar (Android has this issue, iOS is fine). however, mine is half covered by the status bar. i tried using `top` and some figure i got from stackoverflow but to no avail. is there any advice you have for working around this problem? for context, i'm actually trying to contribute to an OSS for the first time. thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score -1):

Just taking the image and ul out of the header made it work.

Comment: you can keep the image within the header. Not causing an issue as my snippet shows